# Laravel5: View [app] not found. resources/views/auth/login.blade.php

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm using Laravel 5 and I have some problems. When I want to access the login on my subdomain

-> http://dev.miweb.com/auth/login

it says:

```
ErrorException in FileViewFinder.php line 140: View [app] not found. (View: 
/home1/miweb/public_html/subdomains/dev/resources/views/auth/
login.blade.php)
```

I don't understand what is the problem. For example, if I come in without the subdomain the file is found.

-> http://miweb.com/subdomains/dev/resources/views/auth/login.blade.php

This file is on my host. It is very confusing because it works on my localhost.

Could the problem be caused by the subdomain? What is the solution?

Thank you

Answer (score 24, accepted):

As you can see in the source of login.blade.php template, it extends layout which is called `app`:

```blade
@extends('app')
```

So, probably there's no `app.blade.php` file in `resources/views` folder. It should be there in order to display the login form.

Answer (score 2):

I set it as: `@extends('layouts.app')`. It works well.

Comment: This worked for me and is simplest. There is a laracasts thread going more into laravelcollective/html issues. Updating the path to the right layout seems easiest! https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/error-saying-route-does-not-exist-when-it-does?page=1

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue I was following the tutorial https://www.flynsarmy.com/2015/02/creating-a-basic-todo-application-in-laravel-5-part-2/ but I created the app.blade.php inside my sub folder. I moved it under the resources/views/ and it worked properly.

Answer (score 0):

---

set it as: @extends('app')
and then we will get it

Answer (score 0):

in previous versions of laravel..master page i.e app.blade.php was present in views folder but in version 5.4 and in upcoming 5.5 its in the separate layouts folder so now code will be @extends('layouts.app')